# isinstance alternative to overwrite default values

Tags: python, pandas

My question is about the `isinstance` function but I'll give an example:

I am trying to implement min-max normalization in pandas, and specifically I need to be able to set arbitrary max and min values.

The following code seems to work:

```py
def normalize_parameter(
    array, 
    fill_na=True, 
    min_bound=True, 
    max_bound=True,
    feature_range=(0, 1), 
    reverse=False
):
    """ Min-max normalization. 
    
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    array : pd.Series
        column to normalize
    fill_na : bool
        NaN policy: fillna with 0 (True) or not (False)
    min_bound, max_bound : bool
        min and max values, default (min, max values of an array)
    feature_range : tuple (min, max), default=(0, 1)
        scale of normalization
    reverse : bool, default=False
    """
    s = array.fillna(0) if fill_na else array
    if isinstance(min_bound, bool):
        min_bound = s.min()
    if isinstance(max_bound, bool):
        max_bound = s.max()
    print(f"{feature_range=}; bounds: {min_bound=}, {max_bound=}; nan policy: {fill_na=}")

    _min, _max = feature_range
    min_max_normalization = _min + ((s - min_bound) * (_max - _min) / (max_bound - min_bound))
    return 1 - min_max_normalization if reverse else min_max_normalization
```

---

```
# takes min and max values of an array  
normalize_parameter(array)
# takes min value of an array and max value of 1
normalize_parameter(array, max_bound=1)
```

---

But I feel this part specifically could be changed and be more pythonic.

```
if isinstance(min_bound, bool):
    min_bound = s.min()
```

I thought this would work:

```
min_bound = min_bound or s.min()
```

But it doesn't if `min_bound = 0` as `0 == False`.

---

Do you think there's a better way or should I stick to `isinstance`?

Comment: Use a sentinel rather than "any bool". `min_bound = True` and `min_bound = False` should not be the same. Use `None` default and `min_bound is not None`. But never `min_bound or other`.

Comment: One question, is it a typo or intended, that you have an underscore before min, but not before max in `_min, max = feature_range`?

Comment: @andrasdeak ah that makes sense! Thank you

Comment: @jottbe didn’t notice that, that’s a typo indeed

Comment: I would also do it like @AndrasDeak suggested, that seems to be the most common way to do such things.